# Using Wire mesh with a Reference Image

Tags: mesh

I am completely new to blender. I rigged a human body (using a YouTube video and Rigify).

I have a 2D image of a man standing in a pose. I would like to pose my newly rigged 3D human body in the exact same pose as man in the 2D image (it’s a photograph of a man actually).

Ideally I would like to to “stretch or adjust” the features of my rigged 3D human body over that of the man in the 2D image so that they exactly match up with his… (the 2D man’s face structure and body structure).

Any suggestions on how I might start to achieve this would be great for me. Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried? What is the issue when you try to "stretch" the rig and human to match the 2D image? maybe some pictures will help or blend file https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: Hi Harry, I haven't tried much other than I am pretty close (Pose-wise) to how my 2D image looks. This "stretch" idea I have comes from Facebuilder's Add-on concept of using a mesh to adjust the facial characteristics of your 3d model over a 2D reference. I think IK allows me to stretch when I am in pose mode, but somehow the mesh (at least in their demo video) looks more precise and less distorted (more natural). Ideally I would like to use this "mesh approach" to make sure my model fits the head and body proportions of my 2D subject's. Is the mesh something I have to create?